# LaTex: How to remove round brackets in the caption of subfigures using \subfloat

Tags: floats

I have the following LaTex code using `\subfloat` to create subfigures:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Sub-Figure-1.png}\label{Sub-Figure-1}} \quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Sub-Figure-2.png}\label{Sub-Figure-2}}
\caption{\textbf{Figure Title}}
\label{Scheme}
\end{figure}
```

The output captions for the subfigures look like this:
[image: Sub-figure captions]

How do I remove the round brackets? Ie. I just want `a` and `b` rather than `(a)` and `(b)`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't just post code fragments, make a [mre] instead. It is very frustrating having to guess all the missing packages etc before even being able to work on your actual problem.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had the full code with all the packages, but had missed putting in `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Will remember next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}


\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\label{Sub-Figure-1}} \quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\label{Sub-Figure-2}}
\caption{\textbf{Figure Title}}
\label{Scheme}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks again @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. This worked!